# Issue with thread handler in Android and CheckBox

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, handler

I want to ask about android thread handler  problem .

Have two "CheckBox" in this code , and when I select it , must to change next Activity

But when I add code in to  thread handler, can't change next Activity.

I already add   in AndroidMainfeat.xml

And I want to ask about "CheckBox" deliver value .

bundle.putString("boy",getText(0).toString().trim()); is Correct ?

thanks.

```
public class PersonalInformation extends Activity{


    private Button setbutton ;
    private CheckBox boy,girl;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal_information);
            setTitle("PersonalInformation");

            buildViews();  //user define
        } 

     private void buildViews(){ 

          boy = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.boy);
          girl = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.girl);         
          setbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setbutton);
          setbutton.setOnClickListener(btsetListener);   
        }
            private OnClickListener btsetListener = new OnClickListener() {     

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    final Runnable callback = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if (boy.isChecked()&&girl.isChecked())
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(PersonalInformation.this, "You can't selected most than two!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            else if (boy.isChecked())
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                    intent.setClass(PersonalInformation.this, meau.class);
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("boy",getText(0).toString().trim());
                                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                    startActivity(intent);                                     
                                }
                            else if (girl.isChecked())
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                    intent.setClass(PersonalInformation.this, meau.class);
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("girl",getText(0).toString().trim());
                                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                    startActivity(intent);                          
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(PersonalInformation.this, "You must selected one!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                        }
                    };

                }   
            };
        }
```

Comment: also add `getText` method code with question

Comment: but only use " bundle.putString("girl",getText().toString().trim()); "

Comment: i mean post code of `getText()` method also